# Cannot seem to call Face ID properly in swift

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have a simple requirement, if the user allows Face ID , open the app after Face ID is successful..

So my app has Face ID enabled

Now I launch the app and each time I do so , the Face ID is checked

I update a published value to true and I can see , that it is updated as well. but some how the check loops...

However the problem is a loop , this process , just keeps repeating, I know I am making a logical error here, can some one please have a look at my code and suggest a few work around, thanks

I call the authentic from my @main

```
import SwiftUI
import LocalAuthentication
import NotificationCenter

@main
struct CollectionApp: App {
    
    @UIApplicationDelegateAdaptor(AppDelegate.self) var appDelegate
    @StateObject var dataController = DataController()
    var body: some Scene {
       
            WindowGroup {
                if dataController.isLocked {
                ContentView()
                
                    .environment(\.managedObjectContext, dataController.container.viewContext)
                
            }
                else {
                    Text("Not authenticated")
                        
                }
        }
        
        
        
    }
  
    
  
}

class AppDelegate: NSObject, UIApplicationDelegate {
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey : Any]? = nil) -> Bool {
     
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(self.updateView), name: UIApplication.didBecomeActiveNotification, object: nil)
        return true
    }

    
    @objc func updateView() {
        print(DataController.shared.isLocked)
        authenticate()
        
    }
    
    func authenticate() {
        let context = LAContext()
        var error: NSError?
        
        if context.canEvaluatePolicy(.deviceOwnerAuthenticationWithBiometrics, error: &error) {
            let reason = "we need to implement face id"
            context.evaluatePolicy(.deviceOwnerAuthenticationWithBiometrics, localizedReason: reason) { success, error in
                if success {
                    DataController.shared.isLocked = true. <—— published value
                } else {
                  //  showAppSettings()
                    print("Not done yet")
                }
            }
        } else {
            //no biometrics
        }
    }
    
    
   


}
```

Comment: Maybe need use NSUserDefaults to save isLocked property? NSUserDefaults stores settings even after restarting the application

Comment: the problem is notification , it just keeps repeating no matter what , how can I stop it from repeating authentication process again and again , thanks

Comment: Add in updateView func "if !DataController.shared.isLocked { authenticate() }

Comment: I tried now the app shows "Not Authenticated" , but runs only once, however now when I reopen the app , the Face ID check is not happening, so the loop stops , but the proper view is now shown + the ID check now happens only once, not each time app is launched by tap on its icon , thanks

Comment: Maybe add in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions authenticate()?

Comment: Ok I tried authenticate only inside , didFinishLaunchingWithOptions, its same behaviour as above, wrong view + now authentication only once, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace

```
  func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey : Any]? = nil) -> Bool {
 
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(self.updateView), name: UIApplication.didBecomeActiveNotification, object: nil)
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(self.willResignActive), name: UIApplication.willResignActiveNotification, object: nil)
    return true
}

@objc func willResignActive() {
    DataController.shared.isLocked = false
}

@objc func updateView() {
    if !DataController.shared.isLocked {
        authenticate()
    }
}
```

and replace

```
@StateObject var dataController = DataController.shared
```

and replace

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
    DataController.shared.isLocked = true
}
```

Comment: I have warning and again the faceid is not checked when we tap on app again, something like every time we swipe up on a phone it checks for Face ID, this checks only once, also a warning like - Publishing changes from background threads is not allowed; make sure to publish values from the main thread (via operators like receive(on:)) on model updates. thanks

Comment: After the DispatchQueue the warning is gone, I am not able to check on Face ID , every time the app icon is tapped to activate it, just once and then the Face ID is not checking , thanks

Comment: OK I added some code to when the app gets to background and Turning the published vat to false again now it works, thanks

Comment: yes , this was very helpful , thanks for your time , very nice of you on weekend to help out